# Customized function to Sum CSV values inside a column

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a string of comma separated numbers inside my column. I want to sum them up so that each individual number in each position are summed up together and give me a new string of numbers. (e.g. [1,2,3,4,5]+[6,7,8,9,0]=[7,9,11,13,5]).

To do that in mysql, I have defined a custom function SUMC in my sql and then run the normal SQL query. This thing works fine when I have lesser rows (5/6) in each group. But when I have say 1000 rows in a group, it just takes infinite time.

Can anybody suggests any better method or an improvement in my code? (I have many columns to sum up in a single query).

MYSQL QUERY:

```
SELECT col1, col2, SUM(num1), SUMC(GROUP_CONCAT(csv1),COUNT(csv1)) FROM `mytable` GROUP BY col1, col2
```

SUMC Function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION SUMC(a TEXT, rop INT)
RETURNS TEXT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE vector,i,j,temp INT;
    DECLARE fin TEXT;
    SET fin = '';
    SET i = 1;
    SET j = 1;
    SET temp = 0;
    SET vector = CHAR_LENGTH(a) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(a, ',', ''));
    SET vector = (vector+1)/rop;

    myloop1: LOOP
    myloop2: LOOP
        SET temp = temp + SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(a,',',(j-1)*vector+i),',',-1);
        IF j = rop THEN
        LEAVE myloop2;
        END IF;
        SET j = j+1;
    END LOOP myloop2;
    SET fin = CONCAT_WS(',',fin,temp);
    SET temp = 0;
    IF i = vector THEN
        LEAVE myloop1;
    END IF;
    SET i = i+1;
    SET j = 1;
    END LOOP myloop1;
    RETURN fin;
END
$$
```

SQL Table:

```
col1     col2  num1    csv1
k1        K2    2      1,2,3
k1        K2    3      4,5,6
k1        K3    4      0,3,6
k1        K3    5      2,4,7
```

Intended Output:

```
col1    col2    num1    csv1
k1       K2      5      5,7,9
k1       K3      9      2,7,13
```

P.S. 1: My current code works perfectly ... only issue is it just takes insane amount of time when I have many rows in a group (let say key1 have 2000 rows to sum)

P.S. 1: In the table, I have around 450 integer columns (like Col1) and 50 Text columns containing comma separated numbers.

Comment: Down voted !!! What is the problem with my question please?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would. The answer's self-evident, isn't it? Don't have a string of comma-separated numbers - or don't bother with an RDBMS.

Comment: well, to have a string of comma separated numbers is not my choice.. I just have to parse an xml file containing hundreds of such fields mixed with thousands more pure number fields .. I need to periodically parse them, sum them up and store them in database ... so, would be very much helpful if you can suggest an alternative ...

Comment: How do you get the xml into mysql? Is there some kind of user interface?

Comment: Actually I am using python to parse the xml file ... after getting values for each header, I insert them into SQL table ... now this data (xml) comes once in every 30 mins with same format .. so I need to insert them  with timestamp .. and I have to sum the values of all header in hourly and daily resolution for reporting.

Comment: So do the processing in python. My guess is that you'll be much happier :-)

Answer (score 0):

Note, I'm not actually advocating this as any kind of solution (I wouldn't do this with an unnormalized environment in SQL). It's just something silly to play with...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,strings VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (strings) VALUES ('1,2,3,4,5'),('6,7,8,9,0');

SELECT i
     , GROUP_CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(strings,',',i),',',-1)) x
     , SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(strings,',',i),',',-1)) y
  FROM my_table
     , ints
 WHERE i BETWEEN 1 AND LENGTH(strings)-LENGTH(REPLACE(strings,',',''))+1
 GROUP 
    BY i;

+---+------+------+
| i | x    | y    |
+---+------+------+
| 1 | 1,6  |    7 |
| 2 | 2,7  |    9 |
| 3 | 8,3  |   11 |
| 4 | 4,9  |   13 |
| 5 | 5,0  |    5 |
+---+------+------+ 

(ints is a table of integers from 0-9)
```

Comment: I guess I was not clear of what I need ... please see updated question .. (if I understand your solution correctly)

Comment: It takes an insane amount of time because (from an RDBMS point of view) it's an insane idea. It cannot use indexes. This is bad.